# How to change a column with date and time as string format in Excel into a column with the same date and time in date/time format?

Tags: string, excel, date, vba

I have a column in string format in Excel (2010) which shows "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" and for an analysis I need it to be exactly the same, except that it is in date+time format instead of string format.

After some googling I got that macros will probably help me, but I never worked with visual basics in Excel before. On top of that, the questions I found which come close to this every time seem to have a very different solution.

I got so far that I have visual basics up to enter some code (yes yes, you may laugh at my poor skills), but I have no clue what code to enter there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get both the date and the time, use `=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA. Use `DATAVALUE` function.

Answer (score 1):

First try formatting the column as dates, you can use your format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" in the Custom Format, Type box.

If this doesn't work then create an extra column using =DATEVALUE(A1) and copy this down the column. Format it as required. You can Copy/Paste Values so that you could then replace the original column.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

and if Excel can interpret the string as a date, it will.